# Choose templated variable based on index

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, metaprogramming

I'm running into an issue with templates and I'm not sure how to fix it in a way that removes the need for (error prone) boilerplate code.

Imagine the following situation, where I want to store a certain amount of data known at **compile time**. The **LOD** value to access the correct mip, is only known at **runtime**. (Note that this is a simplified example):

```
template <byte LOD>
struct ImageStorage {
    constexpr static byte GridSize = 32 >> LOD;

    void SetValueAt(int x, int y, byte value) {
        _data[x + y * GridSize] = value;
    }

    std::array<byte, GridSize * GridSize> _data{};
};

struct MipLevels {
    ImageStorage<0> _lod0; // 32x32
    ImageStorage<1> _lod1; // 16x16
    ImageStorage<2> _lod2; // 8x8
    ImageStorage<3> _lod3; // 4x4
    ImageStorage<4> _lod4; // 2x2
    ImageStorage<5> _lod5; // 1x1

    constexpr void SetValueAt(int x, int y, byte value, byte LOD) {
        x >>= LOD;
        y >>= LOD;
        switch (LOD) {
            case 0:
                _lod0.SetValueAt(x, y, value);
                break;
            case 1:
                _lod1.SetValueAt(x, y, value);
                break;
            case 2:
                _lod2.SetValueAt(x, y, value);
                break;
            case 3:
                _lod3.SetValueAt(x, y, value);
                break;
            //...
        }
    }
};
```

I would like to have something like this, but ofc that isn't possible because the concrete types are not the same.

```
constexpr auto& GetImageStorage(byte LOD) {
    switch (LOD) {
        case 0:
            return _lod0;
        case 1:
            return _lod1;
        case 2:
            return _lod2;
        case 3:
            return _lod3;
        //...
    }
}
```

Is it possible to update the `SetValueAt()` function so it doesn't require the switch? I'm using C++20.

Edit: One requirement is that I need to avoid virtual function calls and heap storage as this would be too large of a performance hit

Comment: You could have a non-template base class with virtual function `SetValueAt`, and have all `ImageStorage` derive from that class. Then `GetImageStorage` would be returning `BaseClass&`. For that matter, you could at that point set up an array of `BaseClass*` pointers, so `SetValueAt` would just do `storages[LOD]->SetValueAt(...)`

Comment: Ah yeah, I forgot to mention. I would like to avoid virtual and heap storage as this would be too large of a performance hit

Comment: No part of this requires heap allocations. An indirection through vtable should be no slower than an indirection through a switch (which likely compiles down to a jump table anyhow).

Comment: Ah yeah good point, I forgot I can just make a pointer to the base class from the stack variables. Hm, let me try that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way is with [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant):

```
constexpr auto GetImageStorage(byte LOD)
-> std::variant<ImageStorage<0>*, ImageStorage<1>*, ImageStorage<2>*, ImageStorage<3>*, ImageStorage<4>*>
{
    switch (LOD) {
        case 0:
            return &_lod0;
        case 1:
            return &_lod1;
        case 2:
            return &_lod2;
        case 3:
            return &_lod3;
        //...
    }
}
```

and then use [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit):

```
constexpr void SetValueAt(int x, int y, byte value, byte LOD)
{
    x >>= LOD;
    y >>= LOD;
    std::visit([&](auto* lod){ lod->SetValueAt(x, y, value); }, GetImageStorage(LOD));
}
```

Comment: I went with this option and it seems to have not made any performance difference. It is a bit ugly to have to put std::visit around every use tho, but I might be able to figure out a way around it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you could accept replace the plain data members with a `std::tuple`, you could consider this solution.

```cpp
struct MipLevels {
    // ImageStorage<0> _lod0; // 32x32
    // ImageStorage<1> _lod1; // 16x16
    // ImageStorage<2> _lod2; // 8x8
    // ImageStorage<3> _lod3; // 4x4
    // ImageStorage<4> _lod4; // 2x2
    // ImageStorage<5> _lod5; // 1x1
    std::tuple<ImageStorage<0>,
            ImageStorage<1>,
            ImageStorage<2>,
            ImageStorage<3>,
            ImageStorage<4>,
            ImageStorage<5>> _lods;

    template <byte LOD>
    ImageStorage<LOD>& GetLod() {
        return std::get<ImageStorage<LOD>>(_lods);
    }
};
```

Use [std::index_sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) and generic lambda introduced in C++20,

```cpp
template <auto value, typename F>
bool call_at(decltype(value) v, F&& f) {
    if (value == v) {
        f.template operator()<value>();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

class MipLevels {
    constexpr static std::size_t lod_num = 5;

    template <typename F>
    constexpr void Call(int v,  F&& f) {
        CallImpl(v, std::make_index_sequence<lod_num>{}, std::forward<F>(f));
    }

    template <auto... Is, typename F>
    bool CallImpl(auto v, std::index_sequence<Is...>, F&& f) {
        return (call_at<Is>(v, std::forward<F>(f)) || ...);
    }


    constexpr void SetValueAt(int x, int y, byte value, byte LOD) {
        x >>= LOD;
        y >>= LOD;

        Call(LOD, [=, this]<auto V> () {
            this->GetLod<V>().SetValueAt(x, y, value);
        });
    }
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qxcEqa6GT)

Comment: This is a good alternative, tho your tuple suggestion has the same issue when I then want to use `GetLod` at the call site. It still requires the template argument. (Ofc that is what your second suggestion resolved)